# How and where do I programmatically add a menu to the Navigation menu?

Tags: 7, theming, routes

I want to add menu items to the Navigation menu dynamically, depending on certain states (example: user is logged in, etc). I assume I do this in theme_preprocess, but I can't seem to find the var to tweak.

Am I looking in the wrong place? Where is the best place to do this, and what is the best method?

Comment: I am having the same needs now. Did you figure out how this can be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest checking out [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6). For example, the following implementation of `hook_menu()` placed in either a module or template.php should insert a menu item into the navigation menu for anonymous users. Take a look at the User module for some good examples of how to implement `hook_menu()` for different user roles.

```
function MODULE_menu() {
   $items = array();
   $items['the/menu/path'] = array(
   'access callback' => 'user_is_anonymous',  //or 'user_is_logged_in' to check if logged in
   'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
   'menu_name' => 'navigation',
   'title' => t('Title of Menu Item'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, that is how to create menus in the menu system. I'm wanting to refine a menu that is defined in the GUI, a built-in nav called Navigation.

Comment: The find the menu item and run the hook_menu_alter on it and add the access callback.

Comment: Themes cannot implement hooks, except specific alter hooks in Drupal 7.

Comment: hook_menu_alter() only runs when the menu system is being rebuilt. I'm looking to refine the menu on the page load.

Comment: Golden oldie! The answer above would be fine. For non-code options, check out https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility, https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_per_role, or https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_menu_perms.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can create it by using `menu_link_save()`.

```
$item = array(
  'link_path' => 'my_path',
  'link_title' => 'title',
  'menu_name' => 'header-top-menu', // Menu machine name, for example: main-menu
  'weight' => 0,
  'language' => $node->language,
  'plid' => 0, // Parent menu item, 0 if menu item is on top level
  'module' => 'menu',
);
menu_link_save($item);
```

You could use the code I am showing in a `hook_update_N()` implementation.

See also [Drupal 7 Menu Link update through update.php](http://bhanu555prakash.blogspot.com/2014/08/menu-link-update-through-updatephp.html).

Comment: FYI - you missed a end quote at the end of 'title