# How to put links in a menu programmatically?

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I'm using Drupal 7, and modules such as [Service links](https://www.drupal.org/project/service_links) and [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag).

I would like to put the links proposed by these modules (share or flag) in a menu (main menu or other).

Anybody know the way to follow?

Comment: This has been answered at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14902/how-and-where-do-i-programmatically-add-a-menu-to-the-navigation-menu

Comment: Thanks pacmaninbw, but how implement the links generate by modules?

Answer (score -1):

Your question is relatively vague, but to answer the title, here's the code you need to use:

```
$link = array(
  'link_title' => t('Your link'),
  'link_path' => 'your-path',
  // Enter the name of the menu where you want this link to appear.
  'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
  'weight' => 0,
);
menu_link_save($link);
```